# How to generate DDL for all tables in a database in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, ddl

How to generate the DDL for all tables in a database of MySQL at once. I know that the following query will output the DDL for a table. But I want DDL of all tables at once because I am having hundreds of tables in my database.

```
show create table <database name>.<table name>;
```

For example:

```
show create table projectdb.customer_details;
```

The above query will result in DDL of `customer_details` table.

I am using MySQL with MySQL workbench on Windows OS.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You can do it using the mysqldump command line utility:

```
mysqldump -d -u <username> -p -h <hostname> <dbname>
```

The `-d` option means "without data".

Comment: I am getting error. Here's my command : mysqldump -d -u root -p pps -h 127.0.0.1 shopping_store;

Comment: What is the error you're getting? It could probably be because of the space between "-p" and your password.

Comment: Upvoted. There is just a syntax error in your answer. The option `-p` does not accept an argument so, if you try to write your password after this option flag, mysqldump will interpret it as the database name. Just use it without `<password>`, it will be requested after you execute the command.

Comment: Interesting, this may have changed (the answer was written in 2011).  You used to be able to put the password on the command line.

Comment: for password use option: 
--password="<pass>"

Comment: `mysqldump  Ver 10.16 Distrib 10.1.23-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64)` works with the syntax of the answer.

Comment: Corrected Syntax Error, command can be like this: mysqldump -d -u root -p -h 10.216.12.11 My_Schema > ./MySchema_DB_DDLs_Dump.sql

Comment: password is asked afterwards bc its unsafe to type passwords in prompts (it can be logged in history etc)

Answer (score 0):

@tftdias above made a comment that is partially correct:

The issue was the space between the -p and 'pps' as the password.  You can absolutely freetext your password on the command line.  You just shouldn't, as a general security rule.  In linux, with a proper configuration, you can add a space (" ") BEFORE the first character on your command line, and that line will not enter into 'history'.  I would recommend that whenever you cleartext your password (don't do it!), that you at least put a space first so that the password is not in visible history.

Answer (score -1):

You must get list of all the tables in database and then run this query.
check this link to get list of all tables:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-tables.php

Comment: That function is deprecated as of PHP 5.5. They recommend using `SHOW TABLES FROM sometable` instead (I think they meant `somedb` though).