# Multiple column IN SELECT with AND matching function

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have two tables, on the first table I have a list of devices with their IDs, account number and the last timestamp that the device update its own status. This table is tiny, have about 50K rows.

On the second table I have all the reports of the all the devices. This table is heavy, at this very moment have about 200.000.000(200 Million) rows.

The big table have three PK columns accountID, deviceID and timestamp

I'm making the query from a VB.NET application

From the first tiny table I get a list of deviceID with their last timestamp to make a query that get some rows on the big table faster.

The problem that I'm facing is that I get some data that I don't need.

Example:

```
 accountID deviceID  timestamp
     1       A         23
     1       A         24
     1       A         25
     1       B         23
```

So, if I want to get the rows with the last timestamp

```
SELECT* FROM clients.Events
WHERE timestamp IN ('25','23')
AND deviceID IN ('A','B')
AND accountID IN ('1')
```

I get

```
 accountID deviceID  timestamp
     1       A         23
     1       A         25
     1       B         23
```

I need to get

```
 accountID deviceID  timestamp
     1       A         25
     1       B         23
```

So, there's any way to match the timestamp with the deviceID?

I know that I can use MAX clause but, as I said before, the Event base is big and I need the result as fast as possible and MAX clause check the whole table and take too much time.

The big Event table is InnoDB.

DDL

```
CREATE TABLE `Events` (
    `accountID` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    `deviceID` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    `timestamp` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `statusCode` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `latitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
    `longitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
    `gpsAge` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    `speedKPH` double DEFAULT NULL,
    `heading` double DEFAULT NULL,
    `altitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
    `transportID` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
    `inputMask` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    `outputMask` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    `address` varchar(90)CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
    `dataSource` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
    `rawData` text,
    `distanceKM` double DEFAULT NULL,
    `odometerKM` double DEFAULT NULL,
    `geozoneIndex` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    `geozoneID` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
    `creationTime` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    `streetAddress` varchar(90)CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
    `city` varchar(40)CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
    `stateProvince` varchar(40)CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
    `postalCode` varchar(16)CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
    `country` varchar(40)CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
    `subdivision` varchar(32)CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
    `speedLimitKPH` double DEFAULT NULL,
    `isTollRoad` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
    `gpsFixType` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    `horzAccuracy` double DEFAULT NULL,
    `vertAccuracy` double DEFAULT NULL,
    `HDOP` double DEFAULT NULL,
    `satelliteCount` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    `batteryLevel` double DEFAULT NULL,
    `batteryVolts` double DEFAULT NULL,
    `signalStrength` double DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`accountID` , `deviceID` , `timestamp` , `statusCode`)
)  ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Relational databases typically work best in set operations.  So think of your problem as one of two different sets.  First set you need the max timestamp for each account and device Id. then you need to join that set to the base set to get what you're after

Comment: If MAX() takes too long, you may need to reconsider your index definitions. Can you provide the DDL for the tables? See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6597966/1483788

Comment: MAX with a GROUP by will work efficiently, provided that there is a suitable index to work against, even better if its the [Clustered Index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-index-types.html)

Comment: If throwing an index on timestamp is viable, I'd go that route, and use the max function.  If that's not a viable solution, just pull in what you have, and sift through it on the vb.net side where you're not dealing with 200M+ records.  A simple linq query against the pulled in data would suffice.  Normally I wouldn't recommend this solution, but it seems you have somewhat of an edge case.

Comment: @wes.hysell DDL added.

Comment: @user2366842 As far I can remember I already tried to add an index but the process take too much and I can't stop that table too much time because I'm not in develop time, the base and all the applications that use that base are running since 4 years ago.

Comment: @E_Blue To reindex a table already used in development time - you could always try to make a copy of the table and then index the copy. When indexing is complete, you can then rename both tables to make the copy match the original. `RENAME TABLE` is wicked fast (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/rename-table.html). To my best recollection, this will not lock your original table by default. However, Your existing index looks like it would work against your query using GROUP and MAX. I would try viewing the `EXPLAIN` plan of your query to determine if it actually is using the defined index.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CE.*
FROM clients.events CE
INNER JOIN (SELECT accountID, DeviceID, Max(timestamp) TS 
            FROM clients.events 
            GROUP YB accountID, DeviceID) CE2
  on CE.AccountID=CE2.accountId
 and CE.DeviceID= CE2.DeviceID
 and CE.TimeStamp = CE2.TS
```

The above gets you the max timestamp record for each device and account
Now you just need to filter...

```
WHERE DeviceID in ('A','B') and accountID = '1' and timestamp in ('25','23')
```

with proper indexes should work efficiently.